# How do I make my Python3 string matching code ignore files that do not match any criteria?

Tags: python-3.6

I have a Python3 script that reads the first eight characters of every filename in a directory in order to determine whether the file was created before or after 180 days ago based on each file's name. The file names all begin with YYYYMMDD or eerasedd_YYYYMMDD_etc.xls. I can collect all these filenames already.

I need to tell my script to ignore any filename that does not conform to the standard eight leading numerical characters, example: 20180922 or eerasedd_20171207_1oIkZf.so.

```
if name.startswith('eerasedd_'):
    fileDate = datetime.strptime(name[9:17], DATEFMT).date()
else:
    fileDate = datetime.strptime(name[0:8], DATEFMT).date()
```

I need logic to prevent the script from choking on files that don't fit the desired pattern. The script needs to carry on with its work and forget about non-conformant filenames. Do I need to add code that causes an exception or just add an elif block?

Answer (score 0):

I have a function to get only the names of those files I need based on their extensions.

```
def get_files(extensions):
    all_files = []
    for ext in extensions:
        all_files.extend(Path('/Users/mrh/Python/calls').glob(ext))

for file in get_files(('*.wav', '*.xml')):
    print (file.name)
```

Now I need to figure out how to check each 'file.name' for the date string in its filename. i.e. now I need to run something like

```
if name.startswith('eerasedd_'):
    fileDate = datetime.strptime(name[9:17], DATEFMT).date()
else:
    fileDate = datetime.strptime(name[0:8], DATEFMT).date()
```

against 'file.name' to see whether the files are 180 days old or less.